# A tag [reactjs] deveria ser sinônimo de [react]?

Tags: debate, tags-sinônimas

A biblioteca se chama [React](https://reactjs.org). Às vezes é chamada de [ReactJS ou React.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)), mas a documentação se refere como React.

No site, a tag [react.js](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react.js) é sinônimo de [react](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react), mas a [reactjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) não é.

A tag [reactjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) deveria ser sinônimo de [react](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react)?

Comment: Dado [essa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252459/64969) e [essa outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252657/64969), ambas as tags se referem a mesma coisa. Portanto, deveriam sim ser sinônimos.

Answer (score 9):

É importante notar que existe React-native e React.js, e talvez esteja havendo confusão entre os usuários quanto ao uso das tags, conforme a resposta do [**SOen**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641772)

- `ReactJS` é uma biblioteca JavaScript, que dá suporte tanto ao front-end, e é usado para construir interfaces para o usuário e **aplicações web**.
- `React Native` é um framework mobile que compila para os componentes de aplicativos nativos (iOS, Android e Windows) em JavaScript e isto permite usar o ReactJS para criar seus componentes dentro dos aplicativos que irá criar.
- ReactJS: https://github.com/facebook/react
- React-native: https://github.com/facebook/react-native

---

### Minha sugestão

Creio que tenhamos que revisar as tags e ajusta-las, minha a sugestão é (para melhorar a experiência dos usuários no site que fizerem perguntas sobre o assunto):

- [react.js](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react.js) para React.js, sendo [react](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react) e [reactjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) como sinônimo para facilitar a experiencia do usuário (creio que seja a sua interpretação).
- [react-native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-native) para se referir somente ao framework para desenvolver aplicativos iOS e Android.

Gostaria da opinião da comunidade sobre o que devemos fazer para facilitar, pois hoje fui analisar a situação e temos 142 perguntas que usam a tag [react](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react) (hoje usada para se referir a lib apenas), creio que todos usuários, principalmente os que mais usam, poderiam opinar.

Comment: @vnbrs eu editei, o intuito era se referir a uma possivel confusão dos usuários, já editei, o resumo da minha resposta é "concordo com a sua visão" precisamos revisar isto ;)

Comment: @vnbrs agora que percebi, eu tinha esquecido do "ponto" na tag, o correto que eu queria dizer é [tag:react.js] sendo a principal (só como opinião mesmo) e react e reactjs seriam seus sinônimos. Assim que a comunidade decidir o melhor poderemos editar a tag considerada principal com uma melhor descrição e Wiki ;)

Comment: Concordo com a primeira abordagem.

Comment: Acho que deveríamos ter um padrão para as tags de libs/framework JavaScript, mas busquei por algumas no SOen e não entendi o padrão deles. O Node refere-se como **Node.js**, Adonis como **AdonisJs**, Angular como **Angular**, AngularJS como **AngularJS**, React como **React** (o twitter é @reactjs), Vue como **Vue.js**, Sequelize como **Sequelize**. As tags hoje (no SOpt) são [node.js], [adonisjs], [angular], [angularjs], [react], [vue.js] e [sequelize-js], no SOen são [node.js], [adonis.js], [angular], [angularjs], [reactjs], [vue.js] e [sequelize.js] ...

Comment: ...  Entendo que Angular deva ser tratado como exceção e está correto como é hoje, de resto acredito que poderiamos usar **.js**, no caso dessa discussão: **[react.js]**

Comment: Para min a tag `react` puramente nem deveria existir para não confundir, deixando apenas `reactjs` e `react-native`, apenas minha opinião...

Comment: @hugocsl o problema é que volta e meia as pessoas criam as tags, acho q tem um sistema de bloqueio, mas não sei se é algo q só CM tem acesso, depois eu confirmo. A motivação de usar como sinonimo era mais para tirar da vista.

Comment: @RafaelTavares concordo contigo q algumas coisas aqui foram feitas de uma forma quando poderiam ter sido "reaproveitadas" do que já estava pronto no SOen, algumas coisas eu realmente desejo a opinião da comunidade, mas outras talvez eu já siga essa linha, fazer ao máximo como é comum entre os devs de tais libs e tecnologias, mas será com o tempo e se isso não for atrapalhar a comunidade (e se ninguém mais discordar)

Comment: Se não for para definir um padrão, temos algum motivo para mudar de [react] para outra coisa? No SOen acho que isso só foi feito por causa da [confusão com ReactPHP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289091/8839059), pelo menos foi a única discussão que encontrei sobre, mas não me lembro de ter visto algum mal uso no SOpt e as [perguntas sobre ReactPHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=reactphp+is%3Aquestion) nunca tiveram a tag [react], então não tivemos esse problema em específico.

Comment: @RafaelTavares otimo ponto!

Comment: por mim que não existisse a tag `react`